# How can I implement a CalendarView dropdown in Action Bar

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to implement a CalendarView in my action bar at the right-top corner for a fragment. I know how I can make a CalendarView.

Here is XML:

```
<CalendarView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/calendarView4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

I couldn't find a tutorial on how to implement this view in the right-top corner of my action bar from a fragment. I want to make the Calender icon dynamic so that the actual date is displayed in it. When the user clicks the Calendar icon, the Calendar should appear with a sliding animation from the bottom of the action bar down.

I know that fragments don't have access to the action bar. So, I think that I have to define the calendar in the fragment and give it back to my navigation activity and append it to my action bar.

[image]

Do you know a solution for this? Or a word I can search about doing it?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to use [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) instead of build in ActionBar if you want to add custom icon to the ActionBar, you can also try to follow with this tutorial: [Tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar)

Comment: I've added my custom icon over a actionbar and it works? Or is this the wrong way? The problem I basicly have is the dropdown action witht the date picker

Comment: And thank you for the tutorial link :) I've read that a toolbar has more option than action bar

Comment: Please take a look also into that tutorial about CoordinatorLayout, I think this is what you need if you want to expand ActionBar after calendar icon click: http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator