# Handle onclick in fragments in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need help with a fragment onclick listener for my `logoutButton`. I want to clear my Shared Preferences and make an Intent. I've read a lot of question on SO but I can't handle this. I've tried it like in an activity from my app but it don't works.

There are a lot of error:

- On my button declaration: Cannot resolve method `findViewById(int)`
- On my shared preferences setup: Cannot resolve method `getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)`
- At the `finish()` statement: Cannot resolve method `finish()`
- At my `new Intent` constructor: Cannot resolve constructor `Intent(de.myfirstapp.app.SettingsFragment, java.lang.Class<de.myfirstapp.app.LoginActivity>)`

```js
package de.myfirstapp.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link SettingsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link SettingsFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public SettingsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    //Change the title in action bar
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        String titleString = getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_navigation_drawer_settings);
        // Set title bar
        ((NavigationDrawerActivity) getActivity())
                .setActionBarTitle(titleString);
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment SettingsFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static SettingsFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        SettingsFragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        //Logout button interaction
        Button logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);

        //Set onclick listener for the logout button
        logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Deleting shared preferences for login activity
                SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = loginPreferences.edit();
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();
                finish();

                // Launching login activity screen
                Intent intentLogout = new Intent(SettingsFragment.this, LoginActivity.class);
                SettingsFragment.this.startActivity(intentLogout);
            }

            ;
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) getActivity();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

You can find my onClick method in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method. Thank you for helping me out off the darkness :)

Comment: The best way to resolve your queries, first learn how to work with fragment and then update your code.

Comment: How did you learn something? About doing it. And what I'm doing here? I learn

Comment: I just meant that your queries are much solvable by yourself only. So look some tutorial of fragment & you will understand the problem. Sorry If you were offended.

Comment: I don't think you are actually learning by asking on stackoverflow that kind of questions and just copy the right code. Your problems are due to lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your on click code to onCreateView(...) method, you can find this button in inflated view, not in fragment itself.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view  =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

    //Logout button interaction
    Button logoutButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);

    //Set onclick listener for the logout button
    logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Deleting shared preferences for login activity
            SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = loginPreferences.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
            getActivity().finish();

            // Launching login activity screen
            Intent intentLogout = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
            SettingsFragment.this.startActivity(intentLogout);
        }

        ;
    });

    return view;
}
```

Other things will work if you add getActivity() method before, like:
    getActivity().getSharedPreferences(...)

Comment: I'll try this code right now :) When I understand it right I need to do this in the onCreateView because this is the function that only have access to the view right?

Comment: It's working great :) I've included a AlertDialog to ask if the user is shure to logout and it's working :D jippi

Comment: Is there a way you can look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/41660641/7267238 It's a hard question I think and because of this nobody answered this :(

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `onCreateView(..)`instead of `onCreate()`

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
       Button your_button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.your_button);
       //...
   }
   ```
2. If you wanna use anything from context, then use `getContext()`. Then you can call `getContext().getSharedPreferences()` or new `Intent(getContext(), ...)`. If you wanna call anything from parent `Activity`, then call it via callbacks or use `Activity` instance via `getActivity()`. For example: `getActivity().finish()`.

But all of these are basics and you should read [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) and [Support Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html).

Answer (score 1):

`Fragment` does not have the `findViewById` method. You should use this method on the view you inflated to create the `Fragment`.

When you inflate the view, save it to a field variable view, and then init your views by:

`view.findViewById(R.id.your_view);`

Answer (score 1):

in your `onCreateView declare the button like below

```
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings,container,false);
Button logoutButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
```

for `finish();` use `getActivity.finish();`

use `getActivity.getSharedPreferences` for sharedpref

for Inten service use

```
Intent intentLogout = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intentLogout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Fragment has the OnCreateView like this.

```
    Button logoutButton;

      @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = new View(getActivity());//you can access your button like this
logoutButton=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);


    return v;
```

Please read [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm) you can understand how to deal with fragments.hope this helps.:)

Answer (score 1):

Get button reference in onCreateView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
    logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
    return view;
}
```

To get shared preferences use

```
SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To finish activity use, move it a under your startActivity call.

```
getActivity().finish();
```

To create intent use

```
Intent intentLogout = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
```